# Как вывести случайный элемент массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Как в моем случае вывести случайное число?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file ('Адрес rss канала');
$xml->channel->item[0]->link;
```

Там где item будет выводит постоянно 0, а мне нужно чтобы цифры менялись.

Вот пример:

```
srand((float) microtime() * 10000000);
$input = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
//echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужен случайный элемент из этой ленты, то видимо как-то так:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file ('Адрес rss канала');
$rkey = array_rand($xml->channel->item);
$xml->channel->item[$rkey]->link;
```

Answer (score 1):

Сокращенно, думаю так:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('Адрес rss канала');
echo $xml->channel->item[rand(0, count($xml->channel->item)-1)]->link;
```

Если разжевать, то так:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('Адрес rss канала'); // получаем массив;
$count_items = count($xml->channel->item); // получаем количество элементов канала;
echo $xml->channel->item[rand(0, $count_items - 1)]->link; // выводим ссылку с рандомным элементом
```